# Android Console Error: "requires .class compatibility set to 5.0. Please fix project properties"

Tags: android, android-manifest, adt, android-build

Just did a fresh Install of Eclipse 3.5 and the Android Platform (SDK's and ADT). I've done this a few times on different machines and so I'm pretty sure I've got everything configured properly.

Tried importing an Android project and received the following error in the console window:

**"Android requires .class compatibility set to 5.0. Please fix project properties."**

I've never seen this error before. The only thing I can think of is that its talking about the build target? I've got the project build target set to 1.6 (API Level 4), Which is where I want it. Seems silly that they would require me to change to a higher API level...

Anyone else see this error before?

Comment: Is your java compiler set to 6?

Comment: I just had this where Eclipse indicated it was set to 1.5. Solution is to set it to something else, then apply, then set back to desired setting (>1.4!) and then apply again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that Android is talking about the Java bytecode format, which you can set in "Window/Preferences", "Java/Compiler/Compiler Compliance Level".

Comment: You are correct, the instructions I found in the blog article I posted simply change the compliance level for that project in particular. The global setting was set to 1.4. I've never had this problem before and have never developed on a Mac before either. I wonder, is it set so low by default on Mac's?

Comment: I don't have a Mac so I don't know about your question specifically, but it is not unusual to see tools that default to 1.4 for compability/legacy reasons. For example, Maven 2 defaults to Java 1.4.

Comment: I have a mac and had to set it to 1.5(I'm using Java 5).  That fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

I had to Rebuild all my Projects when I imported from my Windows machine to the Mac.  Project => Build Project did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just clean the imported project for Project->clean and selecting the project just imported.
it Worked for me. hope would work for you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got a new Windows 7 notebook and also had to set compiler comliance level to 1.5.
On my former Vista workstation and on my MacBook Pro I never ran into that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by doing :

- Clic on your project
- Delete (Don't check "Delete project content on disk")

Clic on :

- Window
- Preferences
- Java
- Compiler
- Check "Use Default compliance settings"
- Apply
- ok

At that point JDT's compiler preferences get properly set to 1.6

- Import your project from your workspace

The error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse and compiling an Android app after upgrading to JDK1.7+?

Try this...

Right-click on the project name in the package explorer.

Select Java Compiler.

Check off enable project specific settings.

Select Compiler compliance level 1.6

Apply/OK.