# how to fix the android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have Eclipse indigo, I can create and run android projects in it , but whenever I import the android project build outside , I getting error which It does not recognize android specific things, it shows error and I see the it underlines all things coming from android or java , for example : it underlines Button,Activity ,MediaPlayer,DatabaseHelper the things you all use or reference in a project.

So, how to fix it .?

Answer (score 2):

There are some reason for red underline showing (Actually R.java file is not generating successfully) in your imported project.

Now If you are finding this kind of error:

> Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0. Please fix project
>   properties.

then the solution is

1. `Package Explorer -> Right click the project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties`
2. set [Compiler compliance level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9732077/379693) as mentioned here

OR simply do:

```
Project -> Clean
```

Comment: It was saying that default.properties file not found for regarding project , so I just change project.properties file to default.properties , so the problem is fixed . 
But anyway, thanks for your all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

try properties -> android -> set the android build target then clean your project

Comment: It was saying that default.properties file not found for regarding project , so I just change project.properties file to default.properties , so the problem is fixed . 
But anyway, thanks for your all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Select your project -> Project -> Clean...->Clean Project Selected Below, select your imported project and Start a build immediately and press OK.

Comment: It was saying that default.properties file not found for regarding project , so I just change project.properties file to default.properties , so the problem is fixed . 
But anyway, thanks for your all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1)
Goto Project> Properties>Enable Project Specific Settings>Set Compliance Level once again to 1.5 and then again to 1.6 the Underline Errors will resolved..

2)
The Alternative is to Uncheck Enable Project Specific Settings and Click on Configure Workspace Settings link then Set Compliance Level once again to 1.5 and then again to 1.6 the Underline Errors will resolved..

Then Bulid the Project...Hope it works for you...